# Euler's theorem and Lagrange's theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Then, by Euler's theorem, I know that
$$
2^{k}\equiv 2^{k\pmod{p-1}}\pmod p. 
$$
From Lagrange I also know that for the order of $2$ modulo $p$ we have
$ ord_p(2)|p-1 \Leftrightarrow \exists m\in\mathbb Z: m\cdot ord_p(2) = p-1.$

But how can I deduce that
$$
2^k \equiv 2^{k\pmod{p-1}} \equiv 2^{k\pmod{ord_p(2)}}\pmod p?
$$

I have no idea how to reduce via the product $ m\cdot ord_p(2)$.

Comment: Euler's theorem _is_ just Lagrange's theorem applied to the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$. Where is the confusion, and what is the context for this question?

Comment: @student91 Let's say I want to solve $2^{17}\pmod{7}.$ By Euler I know $2^{17}\equiv 2^{17 \mod 6} \equiv 2^5\pmod 7$.
But I could also calculate $2^{17}\equiv 2^{17 \mod 3}\equiv 2^2\pmod 7$, because $3$ is the order. But I don't know why I may do that.

Comment: Then after reducing $17\equiv5\pmod{6}$ like you did, you only need to do $2^5\equiv32=28+4\equiv 4\pmod{7}$.

Comment: @student91 I am struggling to proof this in general, that I may reduce modulo order.

Comment: See [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1):

> @student91 Let's say I want to solve $2^{17}\pmod{7}$. By Euler I know $2^{17}\equiv2^{17\pmod{6}}\equiv2^5\pmod{7}$. But I could also calculate $2^{17}\equiv2^{17\pmod{3}}\equiv2^2\pmod{7}$, because $3$ is the order. But I don't know why I may do that.

Given a finite group $G$ (Say $G=(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^\times$) and an element $x\in G$ (Say $x=2$), and a number $m$ which can be written as $m = k\cdot \mathrm{ord}_G(x)+r$, with $k,r,m\ge0$, we have that $$x^m=x^{k\cdot\mathrm{ord}_G(x)+r}=(x^{\mathrm{ord}_G(x)})^k\cdot x^r=1^k\cdot x^r=x^r.$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).